# How do you create a series from $(1,5,7,11,13...)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you create a series formula from $(1, 5, 7, 11, 13...)?$

I know that it's $+4,$ then $+2,$ but I can't seem to determine the formula that generates this.

Note: this is part of an double alternating sequence S0 =  1 - [1/(5 x 3^2)] - [1/(7 x 3^3)] + [1/(11 x 3^4)] + [1/(13 x 3^5)] - - + + ... and so far {(-1)^[n(n-1)/2]} / {(??) x [(3^ n+1)]}

Comment: OEIS gives several [formulae](https://oeis.org/A007310) such as: $$a_n=\frac{6n+(-1)^n-3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a_0=1,$ then $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=3+(-1)^n.$

So $$a_n=1+3n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i=1+3n+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}$$

This can be rewritten an $$a_n=3n+1+n-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor=4n+1-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor$$